# Buddypress hook after image is uploaded

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, buddypress

i want to update a custom user_meta field when a user uploaded a new image (not avatar).

**Working code for avatar upload**

```
add_action('xprofile_avatar_uploaded', 'callback');

function callback($user_id, $type)
{
   // $activity_id = <- the activity from the uploded image.

   update_user_meta($user_id, 'image_'.$activity_id, '1');
}
```

Comment: can you share details about where to upload image in buddypress ?

Comment: the normal picture upload http://DOMAIN.COM/members/USERNAME/media/photo/

Comment: media/photo is not provide buddypress default what is external plugin from buddypress if yes give me plugin name or link which are using plugin.

Answer (score 4):

When you are using rtMedia plugin for buddypress and upload photos provide a action **rtmedia_after_add_media** with three arguments you can handle your customization.

```
add_action( 'rtmedia_after_add_media', 'rtmedia_after_add_media_update_usermeta', 10, 3 );

function rtmedia_after_add_media_update_usermeta( $media_ids, $file_object, $uploaded ){
    // its not provide user id arg so you can get current user id using function get_current_user_id() or $uploaded array have key media_author;
    // $media_ids give all attahment ids when you upload file
    // $file_object give infomation about file like name, path etc
    // $uploaded current upload give settings and update information. Its also gives authore id who is upload media.
    // $user_id = $uploaded['media_author']; 
    $user_id = $uploaded['media_author'];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I overrode `bp_core_avatar_handle_upload` with the following function. It calls bp_core_avatar_handle_upload within it, but avoids an infinite loop by setting and checking the value of a global variable.

```
global $my_bp_group_avatar_upload;
    function my_bp_group_avatar_upload( $upload, $file, $upload_dir_filter )
    {
    // Global.
    global $my_bp_group_avatar_upload;

    // Check upload filter.
    if ( $upload_dir_filter != ‘groups_avatar_upload_dir’ )
    return;

    // Check if this is the second call.
    if ( $my_bp_group_avatar_upload !== 2 )
    {
    // We are being called for the first time!

    // We are about to call the second time.
    $my_bp_group_avatar_upload = 2;

    // Call the function.
    // We’re calling ourselves too, but this time the global equals 2, so we are now in the else statement.
    if ( bp_core_avatar_handle_upload( $file, $upload_dir_filter ) ) {
    // Do stuff here, the upload was a success.
    }

    // We’ve executed the function. We can bail out of the original function run.
    return FALSE;
    } else {
    // We have been called a second time, so set this to something other than 2.
    $my_bp_group_avatar_upload = 0;

    // We want to continue with the execution.
    return TRUE;
    }
    }
    add_filter( ‘bp_core_pre_avatar_handle_upload’, ‘my_bp_group_avatar_upload’, 10, 3 );
```